# Compress several files with different names

Tags: linux

Example:
I have 100 files each 1 with a name like this:
g1001_1_405901_828719213.arc
g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc
g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc

up to 405999

I want to make a tar.gz of each file by changing their name to g1001_1_405901_405901.tar.gz

can you do all of them at once with your new name?

Comment: Are you aware that by just changing a filename you will convert these files into tarballs?

Comment: Yes, but I have a script that takes and unzips the files. So I need them to be on .tar.gz

Comment: Sorry, I meant `you will *NOT* convert these files into tarballs`

Comment: no problem i already did one by one but as there are more than 2 thousand files it takes too long i wanted a script to do that.

Comment: Tar is for putting many files into one, and Gzip for compression. A tar.gz file only containing one file each is pretty much useless and has an unnecessary overloard, therefore compressing the files should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question...

Are you trying to take files that have a similar name and combine all with a similar name into a single tar.gz file?

For example, in your question, you mention "g1001_1_405901_828719213.arc g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc" and that they go up to "405999".

If this means that you have lots of files that begin with g1001_1_405901 and the last part of the name ("_828719213.arc") is what varies, then you should be able to use a wildcard to match the name up to the point where they deviate.

So, for example, to tar up all files that start with g1001_1_405901, you could use something like:

```
tar -czvf g1001_1_405901.tar.gz ./g1001_1_405901_*.arc
```

If that is not your question, and you simply want to compress the files in the directory that match a pattern, then you could use something like:

```
gzip g1001_1_405901.*.arc
```

Your question isn't very clear.  If neither of these are what you are looking for, perhaps you can edit your question and give more details.

Comment: For example, in your question, you mention "g1001_1_405901_828719213.arc g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc" and that they go to "405999".
Correct, but I need that when making a .tar.gz it should keep each file separate and with a different name that would be g1001_1_405901_405901.tar.gz
g1001_1_405902_405902.tar.gz
g1001_1_405903_405903.tar.gz

Comment: If that means you have a lot of files that start with g1001_1_405901 and the last part of the name ("_828719213.arc") is what varies, you should be able to use a wildcard to match the name to the point where they deviate .

No, What varies is the part where this 405901 goes up to 405999.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use Perl implementation of `rename` program (there is
another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux`
package). Example - first let's re-create a list of files you
presented in your question:

```
$ touch g1001_1_405901_828719213.arc g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc
$ ls -Al
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 11 21:30 g1001_1_405901_828719213.arc
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 11 21:30 g1001_1_405902_828719213.arc
```

run `perl-rename` and list files again:

```
$ perl-rename 's,_[0-9]+.arc,.tar.gz,;s,_([0-9]+)\.tar.gz,_\1_\1.tar.gz,'  *
$ ls -Al
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 11 21:30 g1001_1_405901_405901.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 11 21:30 g1001_1_405902_405902.tar.gz
```